# Interview: Renaming all files in a directory using a data structure

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, runtime, file-rename

This is a problem I have encountered in a tech interview. You have 500,000 files in a directory, which is configured so that they are always in alphabetical order. They have names as such:

- Afile
- Bfile
- File00000001
- File00000002

...

You want to rename all the files **while preserving their order** as such:

- File00000001
- File00000002
- File00000003

...

You can probably see the obvious issue here. If you rename Afile into File00000001, it will collide with the existing file with the same name and also the order will be altered, which is not what we want.

The question here is, how can you devise an algorithm with the most optimal run-time to do the renaming task efficiently?

Comment: can you just rename all files with `FileXXXXXX` appended to the end of the name. Order shouldn't change and then go through a second time, removing the beginning of each name.

Comment: It seems the files are in sorted order. Why don't you just choose the last file name and start replacing each of the files increasingly?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot go through the files in ascending order and also not in decending order, both could lead to a conflict. Also renaming the files to something else first could potentially lead to a conflict. The goal seems to be to rename each file only once, so you can do something as follows:

```java
private static File dir;

public static void renameFiles(String path) {
    dir = new File(path);
    File[] files = dir.listFiles();
    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
    int number = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++)
        if (files[i].isFile())
            map.put(files[i].getName(), "File" + pad(number++));
    // so we created a map with original file names and the name it should get
    for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++)
        if (!files[i].getName().equals(map.get(files[i].getName())) // not same name
            renameFile(files[i].getName(), map);
}

private static void renameFile(String file, Map<String, String> map) {
    String newName = map.get(file);
    if (newName != null) {
        if (map.containsKey(newName))
            renameFile(newName, map)
        File f = new File(dir, file);
        f.renameTo(new File(dir, newName));
        map.remove(file);
    }
}
```

Time complexity O(n). We recursively go ahead until we don't have a renaming conflict any more and then start renaming from the tail. There won't be a conflict because it is possible that File004 becomes File007 or that File007 becomes File004 but not both, so no circular renaming. If there are too many files then recursion depth might not be sufficient and we have to implement it with a stack, but it is the same principle.

```java
private static void renameFile(String file, Map<String, String> map) {
    String newName = map.get(file);
    if (newName != null) {
        Stack<String> stack = new Stack<>();
        do {
            stack.push(file);
            file = newName;
            newName = map.get(file);
        } while (newName != null);
        while (!stack.empty()) {
            file = stack.pop();
            File f = new File(dir, file);
            f.renameTo(new File(dir, map.get(file)));
            map.remove(file);
        }
    }
}
```

This will work on Linux, but for Windows you could still have problems, because the file names are not case sensitive. You could store all the keys in the map as lower case and always call toLowerCase() when accessing the map.

Comment: How could decending order lead to a conflict? And how is upper/lowerCase relevant?

Comment: 1. E.g. {File003, X, Y}, you will rename Y to File003 which already exists. 2. On windows file003 and File003 is the same, so if you only check if the name File003 exists you still overwrite file003.

Comment: a) You want to rename File003 to File005, but File 005 has already been renamed to File007, if you work in descendant order. b) There was no hint, that files with similar names exist. Why isn't file005 renamed to File007 if such names are treated as equal? Isn't the treatment consistent? I would abandon the assumption without hint about filesystem. It's about 500.000 files, all in one naming scheme, +FileA and B.

Comment: @userunknown I disagree, this was only an example given by the author of the question to illustrate where the problems are. In my opinion you cannot make any assumptions about the file names. {File003, File004, File005} same example more or less, shows why it doesn't work.

Comment: If you have access to a bash shell, test my script. `They have names as such` means, afaik, that we see the begin of the series which is continued, until File00500000 or File00499998. Why else is some naming pattern introduced?

Comment: @userunknown well then why should we use a data structure? Wouldn't be an interesting interview question.

Comment: Maybe it's a trap?

Comment: @userunknown https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/as-such American (which the author of the question is): 
as being what is indicated or suggested. Then you go to suggest: If you suggest something, you put forward a plan or idea for someone to think about. Also "such as" means "for example", maybe he just switched the words.

Comment: @maraca yeah I meant "such as." BTW I really like your solution you are a freaking genius

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in {100..1..-1} ; do o=$(printf "File%04d" $i); n=$(printf "File%04d" $((i + 2))); echo mv $o $n; done;
```

or better readable:

```
for i in {100..1..-1}
do 
   o=$(printf "File%04d" $i)
   n=$(printf "File%04d" $((i + 2)))
   echo mv $o $n
done
```

FileA and FileB can be renamed by hand.

You have to adapt the size, but for testing, a human number of files seemed more appropriate to me.

Ah, yes, that's bash-syntax; important to notice. And it doesn't mv files yet, only echos the mv-command.

Don't try to run it in parallel. :)

But you could as well move them in opposite, normal order to a new dir, and then move them all back into the old dir, to prevent overriding. This would allow to perform it in parallel.

The for-statement is equivalent to what is elsewhere known as

```
for (i = 100; i >=1; --i)
```

and

```
printf "File%04d" $i
```

prints a 4 digit i with leading zeros.